# My output filter is not working on (apache)Oracle http server 12.1.3

Tags: apache, http, filter, output

I have written a customized Apache module with outputfilter. This is for OHS 12.1.3 SPARC  64bit. Upon LoadModule module get loaded and logs in FilterRegisterHooks get generated. But After accessing the web pages output filter never gets called.
This works fine on Apache on other machines.

```
//This log get generated on LoadModule

static void myFilterRegisterHooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    apr_file_t *filetest = NULL;
    apr_status_t rv;

    ap_register_output_filter(Out_myFilterName, myFilterOutFilter, NULL, AP_FTYPE_RESOURCE);
    {
    rv = apr_file_open(&filetest, FILEDIRE, APR_FOPEN_WRITE | APR_FOPEN_CREATE | APR_FOPEN_APPEND, 0, p);
    rv = apr_file_printf(filetest, "\nMessage --> %s", "Inside myFilterRegisterHooks");
        apr_file_close(filetest);
    }
}
```

But on accessing website below log never get generated

```
static apr_status_t myFilterOutFilter(ap_filter_t *f, apr_bucket_brigade *bbIn)
{
    apr_file_t *filetest123 = NULL;
    apr_status_t rv123; 
    {
    rv123 = apr_file_open(&filetest123, FILEDIRE, APR_FOPEN_WRITE | APR_FOPEN_CREATE | APR_FOPEN_APPEND, 0, f->r->pool);
    rv123 = apr_file_printf(filetest123, "\nMessage --> %s", "##### Inside myFilterOutFilter #####");
    apr_file_close(filetest123);
    }
    {   
    apr_bucket *bcktIn;

//remaining code...........
```

I tried giving directive "AllowOverride All" in perticular directory.
Checked all error log files no any error log generated for this.
Please let me know if something is not configured properly.